# scala - convert byte[] to case class instance

Tags: mongodb, scala

I stored one of my case class instance 'Alert' as binary in mongoDB.
I have to read and type cash to 'Alert'.

I tried this

```
object MongoMain extends App {
val uri = new MongoURI("url")
  val mongoColl = MongoConnection(uri)("testdb")("alert")
  val q = MongoDBObject("_id" -> ObjectId.massageToObjectId("5269c718ebb2e54b950a1cc1"))
  //  println(mongoColl.findOne(q))
  mongoColl.find(q).foreach { z ⇒
    z.get("message").getClass match {
      case data: Class[Binary] ⇒ println(data.getSimpleName)
      case _                   ⇒
    }
  }
}
```

This printing byte[], ie, it retriving message field as byte[] after I have to convert it to Alert. how can I do that, need help:

Comment: How did you store the case class as binary? What format did you use there? Java object serialization?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the follow function,hope it helpful.

```
def deserializeAlert(data: Array[Byte]): Alert ={
    try {
      val in = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data))
      val alert = in.readObject.asInstanceOf[Alert]
      in.close()
      alert
    }
    catch {
      case cnfe: ClassNotFoundException => {
        cnfe.printStackTrace()
        null
      }
      case ioe: IOException => {
        ioe.printStackTrace()
        null
      }
    }
  }
```